# Parse Notification .net UTF-8 format

Tags: c#, android, .net, web-services, parse-platform

I am using Parse .Net api for `PushNotification` for android. My `Webservice` is here

```
private bool PushNotification(string pushMessage)

{
    bool isPushMessageSend = false;
    string postString = "";
    string urlpath = "https://api.parse.com/1/push";
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlpath);
    postString = "{ \"channels\": [ \"Trials\"  ], " +
                     "\"data\" : {\"alert\":\"" + pushMessage + "\"}" +
                     "}";
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.ContentLength = postString.Length;
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-Parse-Application-Id", "My Parse App Id");
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-Parse-REST-API-KEY", "My Rest API Key");
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
    requestWriter.Write(postString);
    requestWriter.Close();
    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        JObject jObjRes = JObject.Parse(responseText);
        if (Convert.ToString(jObjRes).IndexOf("true") != -1)
        {
            isPushMessageSend = true;
        }
    }
return isPushMessageSend;
}
```

This code works correctly for English alphabet. But when i try to use letter like "ü","ş","ö","ç" etc. Error occurred.

Error is here

```
System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled. ---> System.IO.IOException: Cannot close stream until all bytes are written.
  at System.Net.ConnectStream.CloseInternal(Boolean internalCall, Boolean aborting)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace -
  at System.Net.ConnectStream.CloseInternal(Boolean internalCall, Boolean aborting)
  at System.Net.ConnectStream.System.Net.ICloseEx.CloseEx(CloseExState closeState)
  at System.Net.ConnectStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
  at System.IO.Stream.Close()
  at System.IO.StreamWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
  at System.IO.StreamWriter.Close()
```

How can i solve this problem.

Thanks for help

Comment: "error occurred" doesn't give us any information about *where* you got the error, or what it looked like. *Always* give information about any errors you receive. (Additionally, we don't know what encoding the web server is using.)

Comment: where does the error occuur? any call stack?

Comment: @matt i add error sorry for this mistake

Comment: As a side note: you might want to use an actual json serializer / formatter - or at the very least add some escaping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go:

```
httpWebRequest.ContentLength = postString.Length;
```

You have assumed that each character is one byte, which is not always the case. You can calculate the UTF-8 length via `Encoding.GetByteCount(s)` - use that instead.

```
httpWebRequest.ContentLength = myEncopding.GetByteCount(postString);
```

Or even better: pre-compute the payload:

```
var data = myEncopding.GetBytes(postString);
httpWebRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
//...
requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved using the following code:

```
public bool SendPushNotification(string jsonContent)
{
    string urlpath = "https://api.parse.com/1/push";
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(urlpath);
    request.Method = "POST";
    string appId = "...";
    string restApiKey = "...";

    request.Headers.Add("X-Parse-Application-Id", appId);
    request.Headers.Add("X-Parse-REST-API-KEY", restApiKey);

    System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    Byte[] byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(jsonContent);

    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    request.ContentType = @"application/json";

    using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    }

    try
    {
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            long length = response.ContentLength;
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                JObject jObjRes = JObject.Parse(responseText);
                if (Convert.ToString(jObjRes).IndexOf("true") != -1)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        // Log exception and throw as for GET example above
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```